# In how many ways can you arrange $n$ books on $k$ bookshelves (order of books matters) if there has to be 1 book on each bookshelf?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I know how to solve this question if the condition of having at least 1 book on each bookshelf is not included. Then the answer would be $$
n ! \cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+k-1 \\
k-1
\end{array}\right)
$$
But I don't know how to solve this question with the added condition.

Comment: First clarify which objects are distinct, and which are identical

Comment: Assuming order on bookshelves matter, books distinct, and shelves distinct, you can use the same approach but with the other form of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), getting $n!\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.  If books and/or shelves are not distinct then other answers happen.

Comment: The Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion might help you.

Comment: Typesetting tip:  You can produce $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in $n!\cdot{n-1 \choose k-1}$ ways.

First arrange the books in $n!$ ways. Now of the $n-1$ gaps between them, choose $k-1$ to act as boundaries between these. This gives the answer.